# ast.literal_eval - loop over string elements in a list

Tags: python, django, list, tuples

**Goal**: I want to extract longlat tuples in the `map` key from a `request.POST` below.

```
<QueryDict: {'map': ['(38.70053557156445, 149.81571853160858)', '(38.70060091643143, 149.8153966665268)'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ###}>
```

**Problem**: I used `ast.literal_eval` to extract the tuples but somehow only 2nd tuple is returned.

```
markers = request.POST
position = ast.literal_eval(markers['map'])
```

I also tried looping over `map` with but this is giving me `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` on tuple parentheses.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(markers['map']):
 position = ast.literal_eval(markers['map'][idx])
```

Finally, I tried `list(map(ast.literal_eval, markers['map']))`, but this returns the same `SyntaxError` as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s common for query strings to be used to represent both keys with single values and keys with multiple values, so Django’s `QueryDict` [requires that you specify the type you’re looking for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
position = list(map(ast.literal_eval, markers.getlist('map')))
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!! Thanks milllions :)